# When you're going to remove all the obstacles "from your way"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine you as a prime minister of a country are giving a speech in a congress about the current status of the economic affairs in the country. You intend to indicate that there are lots of stumbling blocks in our **way** [all have an identical way because they are considered as one single union] and we have to remove it to arrive at success. Doe the sentence bellow work in natural English? If not, then please tell me how it would be better sounding and more idiomatic to be said:

> - We must remove all obstacles **from our way**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We must remove all *the* obstacles *(that are)* in *(our)* way.

I think you are thinking since you are using *remove* you want to use *from*

> remove the fallen tree *from* the path

However, things that block one's path are considered

> *in the way*.
>   I could not get off the bus, too many people were *in the way*.